# How to add a third single quote in a python variable?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc and python.
My goal is to update a column in the db in order to delete square bracket and a single quote at the beginning. I would like to do it directly with a sql command called by python.

What I would like to do in sql is:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Artist]
SET ARTIST = REPLACE(ARTIST, '[''', '')
```

I'm not able to write the statement in a python variable due to the quotes. I was writing something like:

```
sql_delete_square_brackets = '''
UPDATE [dbo].[Artist]
SET ARTIST = REPLACE(ARTIST, '['', '')
'''
```

Obviously doesn't work (quotes are missing)

How can I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL for MS SQL Server (and many other SQL dialects) a single-quote inside a string literal is simply doubled-up, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO person (lastname) VALUES ('O''Rourke')
```

so I suspect that in your case you could use

```py
sql_delete_square_brackets = """\
UPDATE [dbo].[Artist]
SET ARTIST = REPLACE(ARTIST, '[''', '')
"""
```

Notice that the python string uses `"""` instead of `'''`. We usually use double-quotes for SQL statements in Python code precisely because we may want to have a single quote (SQL string literal) in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to mix double and simple quotes :
like so :

```
sql_delete_square_brackets = """
UPDATE [dbo].[Artist]
SET ARTIST = REPLACE(ARTIST, '['', '')
"""
```

and if your database allow it, like so :

```
sql_delete_square_brackets = """
UPDATE [dbo].[Artist]
SET ARTIST = REPLACE(ARTIST, "['", "")
"""
```